# What did evolution install and how can I safely remove all of it, wihtout screwing up unity?

Tags: unity, 13.04, uninstall, evolution

I installed evolution briefly, didnt like it and tried uninstalling.

```
$ sudo apt-get purge evolution
```

After I checked what else was installed called evolution

```
$ dpkg -l | grep -i evolution
    ii  evolution-data-server                     3.6.4-0ubuntu1                         amd64        evolution database backend server
    ii  evolution-data-server-common              3.6.4-0ubuntu1                         all          architecture independent files for Evolution Data Server
    ii  libcamel-1.2-40                           3.6.4-0ubuntu1                         amd64        Evolution MIME message handling library
    ii  libebackend-1.2-5                         3.6.4-0ubuntu1                         amd64        Utility library for evolution data servers
    ii  libebook-1.2-14                           3.6.4-0ubuntu1                         amd64        Client library for evolution address books
    ii  libecal-1.2-15                            3.6.4-0ubuntu1                         amd64        Client library for evolution calendars
    ii  libedata-book-1.2-15                      3.6.4-0ubuntu1                         amd64        Backend library for evolution address books
    ii  libedata-cal-1.2-18                       3.6.4-0ubuntu1                         amd64        Backend library for evolution calendars
    ii  libedataserver-1.2-17                     3.6.4-0ubuntu1                         amd64        Utility library for evolution data servers
    ii  libfolks-eds25                            0.8.0-1                                amd64        Evolution-data-server backend for libfolks
    ii  nautilus-sendto                           3.6.1-0ubuntu1                         amd64        integrates Evolution and Pidgin into the Nautilus file manager
```

Trying to uninstall any of these packages will also uninstall ubuntu-desktop. On top of that I have a proccess running after boot called `evolution-source-registry`.

How can I get rid of all the evolution stuff without destroying ubuntu-desktop?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

While some parts of `evolution` will be installed, and in use (they are required by other parts of the system, including the clock indicator, and empathy), there are a couple of minor things, which should get removed if you run `sudo apt-get autoremove --purge`. This will remove any libraries or such which were automatically installed, but are no longer needed. In this case. I think `libcamel-1.2-40` will be removed, as it isn't really needed by the calendar or address book integration, possibly with some other packages external to evolution (such as older kernel versions).

Comment: autoremove doesn't pick up any of these packages

Answer (score 0):

Hm, actually all these packages are installed by the indicator-datetime package.

```
  evolution-data-server evolution-data-server-common indicator-datetime
  libcamel-1.2-40 libebackend-1.2-5 libebook-1.2-14 libecal-1.2-15
  libedata-book-1.2-15 libedata-cal-1.2-18 libedataserver-1.2-17
```

That seems a bit excessive to show the current time. Any alternatives that work?